# Batch automating Plink two-hop telnet session

Tags: batch-file, telnet, plink

I am trying to use Plink to telnet into a system, once logged in it will need to telnet again into another device from there.  The problems I am having is in using the telnet command inside of Plink.  It thinks it needs to start a new telnet session instead of just sending the command.

Here is the batch command, the Plink file location and IP are already set as variables obviously, I have no problems with connecting to the first device and passing commands:

```
!plink! !ip! -telnet <commands.txt
```

inside of the `commands.txt` I have:

```
telnet (specified IP address)
(username)
(password)
execute commands
```

I have also tried combining the username into the IP such as

```
telnet username@(specified IP address)
(password)
```

or

```
telnet -pw password username@ipaddress
```

The first device in Linux and the second is running QNX.  I appreciate any help!

Comment: "The problems I am having": Can you be more specific, what does it do?

Comment: It had been a while since I attempted this so I tried it again to verify the issue:  After it initiates the telnet session it requests the username and password, trying to pipe the commands in for username and password will not work. I guess I need a way to specify it such as user@!ip! -pw password